# Calculating the integral of analytic functions inside and outside the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

Calculate the integral:

$$I = {1 \over {2\pi i}}\int_r {{{\omega (t) \cdot \overline {\varphi(t)} } \over {t - {z_0}}}} dt$$
where $r$ is a curve on the positive unit circle, ${{z_0}}$ is a point **outside** the unit circle.

${\omega (z)}$ has a first-order pole ${{z_k}}$ **inside** the circle and is analytical on the unit cicle.

$\varphi (z)$ is given by the following form:
$$\varphi (z){\rm{ = }}{{{a_1}} \over z} + {{{a_2}} \over {{z^2}}} +  \cdots  + {{{a_n}} \over {{z^n}}},\quad z \ge 1$$
$\varphi (z)$ is analytic **outside** the unit circle.
The complex conjugate of $\varphi (z)$ is as follows:
$$\overline {\varphi (z)} {\rm{ = }}{{{{\bar a}_1}} \over {\bar z}} + {{{{\bar a}_2}} \over {{{\bar z}^{\rm{2}}}}} +  \cdots  + {{{{\bar a}_n}} \over {{{\bar z}^n}}}$$
$\overline {\varphi (z)} $ is an analytic function **inside** the unit circle.
Since ${{z_0}}$ is **outside** the unit circle and ${z_k}$ is **inside** the unit circle, according to the residue theorem, we have:

$$\displaylines{
  I = {1 \over {2\pi i}}\int_r {{{\omega (z) \cdot \overline {\varphi (z)} } \over {z - {z_0}}}} dz \cr 
  {\rm{ = }}{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} {\rm{s}}({{\omega (z) \cdot \overline {\varphi (z)} } \over {z - {z_0}}},z = {z_k}) \cr 
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to {z_k}} ((z - {z_k}) \cdot {{\omega (z) \cdot \overline {\varphi (z)} } \over {z - {z_0}}}) \cr 
   = {{\overline {\varphi ({z_k})} } \over {{z_k} - {z_0}}} \cdot \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to {z_k}} ((z - {z_k})\omega (z)) \cr} $$
In the calculation of ${\overline {\varphi ({z})} }$ , I think that it should be computed by substituting $z=z_k$. However, in the paper, it is considered as $$\overline {\varphi ({1 \over {{{\bar z}_k}}})} $$
This has left me feeling confused.
I look forward to your response or assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general $\overline{\varphi}$ is not analytic inside the unit circle. Therefore, the residue theorem is not directly applicable. Instead, you can use that $\overline{z}=1/z$ on $r$, thus you can substitute $\overline{\varphi(z)}$ by $\varphi(1/z)=\overline{a_1}z+\dots+\overline{a_n}z^n=:\psi(z)$ in the integral. The latter function is a polynomial and therefore analytic, hence the residue theorem is applicable. Then, you get $\psi(z_k)$ in your computation which coincides with $\overline{\varphi(1/\overline{z_k})}$ as stated in the paper.